# How can I remove attribute PSEUDONYM from the X509SubjectName before validating a XAdES-T message

Tags: java, certificate, xades4j

At the moment we are receiving certificates which contain an attribute PSEUDONYM in the subject name.
When instantiating a X500Name object, java gives an Exception.

How can I remove the PSEUDONYM attribute from the subject name before applying a verify on the signature for a XAdES-T message.
Example subject name:
C=NL,O=test,OU=Software,CN=DUMMY :PN,serialNumber=1,pseudonym=DUMMY :PN

Answer (score 0):

At the moment I'm pretty sure it is allowed.
So I'll post an other question how to achieve it.